# Antdesign Select z-index problem with Portal

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have something like this:

```
<Portal>
  <BigComponent>
     <Select options={[...]} />
  </BigComponent> 
</Portal>
```

The select options are created in a div next to the BigComponent one. The BigComponent div is absolutely positioned with a high z-index.

This makes it so that it covers the options of the dropdown. I can fix it in dev tools by giving position relative to the div that Antd creates and giving it a high z-index, but the problem is it has no selector so no way of targeting it.

Any fix?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! There's a prop `getPopupContainer` that takes a function which returns a selector, I just selected my BigComponent div and it works fine now :)